# Deserialize JSON with an array of Custom Objects using Json.NET

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, root

I received a JSON file, which contains a root element "users", and a list of "user" items.

I'm trying to deserialize the json into a `List` of a custom class called `User`, but I keep getting a `JsonSerializationException`, that it can't cover it.

I tried the following:

Code:

```
 public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public JObject Exception { get; set; }
}
```

And -

```
public Response DeserializeJSON(string json)
    {
        Response deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
        return deserialized;
    }
```

JSON:

```
    {
  "Users": {
        "User": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "active": "true",
            "name": "Avi"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "active": "false",
            "name": "Shira"
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "active": "false",
            "name": "Moshe"
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "active": "false",
            "name": "Kobi"
          },
          {
            "id": "5",
            "active": "true",
            "name": "Yael"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Sorry for bad styling!!

Comment: Did you make sure that JSON was valid? Try dumping it here http://jsonlint.com/ and see it there ain't some problems in JSON itself.

Comment: It was the first thing I did :) It's indeed valid.

Answer (score 0):

In your Response class, try initializing the collection in the constructor.

```
public class Response
{
    public Response()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
    public JObject Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Next thing to try is keep code above but change the collection type to IEnumerable (keep as List in constructor). I have edited the solution above

Comment: Still doesn't work. On debugging, it does get to the Response's constructor, but the List<User> remains empty.

Comment: Could the problem be with the JSON-
I now notice that it's actually a "Users" object, holding a "User" object, which holds an array of objects. maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yes - The both capitalisation of the field names in the User object is wrong (should be uppercase ID, Active and Name) and the User should be deleted - "Users" is the collection

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you please edit your reponse with the correct code? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I need start reading the JSON better... :)
My problem was that there were infact 2 "wrappers" to this JSON string:

The root element was "Users", which held an element called "User".
This fixed it:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public ResponseContent users { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseContent
{
    public List<User> user;
}
```

Thanks! :)